# Does a Deep Neural Network requires the feature vectors to be uncorrelated, to perform best?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning

Does a Deep Neural Network requires the feature vectors to be uncorrelated, to perform best?

Comment: What does "close to diagonal" mean? Do you just mean that the off diagonal elements are 'close' to 0? Are the diagonal elements 1, <1, or >1?

Comment: @gung : by Diagonal, I mean off diagonal elements are close to zero! no intention to  restrictions on diagonal elements.

Comment: It might help if you could paste in an example of the kind of covariance matrix you have in mind. If the diagonal elements are all 1, you have a *correlation* matrix, & "close to 0", while vague, would mean that your features are almost perfectly uncorrelated. OTOH, if the diagonal elements are <1, "close to 0" can be quite high correlations.

Comment: @gung : Simply speaking, I mean off diagonal elements are negligible when compared to diagonal elements by say an order of magnitude! There is no confusion about what I am asking here!

Comment: @gung : I am interested in a regression task and I am talking about covariance of the output features (that need to be approximated in regression). I am not that concerned about input features.

Comment: Also assume activation of output layer is linear.

Answer (score 3):

In general, neural network (deep learning) can automatically learn the feature transformation to make a better model. For example, if you have 0 variance features, i.e., every data has same value, the neural network will automatically ignore it.

Think about widely used example in neural network, handwritten digit recognition with [MNIST data](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/). Many models directly use all pixels as features. There are a lot of 0 variance features and many features are closely correlated. (Intuitively, the corner pixel may always be white for all images, and if current pixel is black, it is very likely next pixel is the same color.)

Therefore, it does not matter too much if you have correlated or uncorrelated features. What it matter is how much are the features related to the label.

Comment: I would have thought it would be analogous to the multiple regression case, in which correlations make it harder to learn the unique contributions of the individual features, & that the more correlated they are, the more data you need.

Comment: @gung : I am interested in a regression task and I am talking about covariance of the output features (that need to be approximated in regression). I am not that concerned about input features.

Comment: Also assume activation of output layer is linear.